# decltype as a return type in class member function

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I got error compiling below code.

```
struct B{
    double operator()(){
        return 1.0;
    }
};

struct A {
    auto func() -> decltype(b())
    {
        return b();
    }

    B b;
};
```

However, if I reorganize the `A`, it compiles.

gcc 4.8 said that 'b' was not declared in this scope.

```
struct A {
    B b;
    auto func() -> decltype(b())
    {
        return b();
    }
};
```

So, what is wrong with the first??

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are trying to ask.  'Is it valid?' may be a bit too vague for the community to fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: @JeffWolski: Yes I agree, so I revised the wording:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The definition of the `class` is processed it two passes: first the member declarations are collected, including function *signatures*, and then the bodies of definitions are parsed.

The function body therefore has access to all member declarations, including subsequent ones, but the function prototype only sees preceding declarations.

Comment: The late return type is not part of the body/definition though. E.g. it can appear in a declaration only.

Comment: Yes. Using `auto … ->` moves the return type syntactically, and allows you to use the parameter names in the return type, but that's the only difference.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it valid?

Your last example is well-formed, while the first one is not (so GCC is correct).

Paragraph 3.4.1/7 on unqualified name lookup specifies:

> A name used in the definition of a class `X` **outside of a member function body**, default argument, *brace-or-
>   equal-initializer* of a non-static data member, or nested class definition **shall be declared in one of the
>   following ways**:
>
> — **before its use in class `X`** or be a member of a base class of X (10.2), or
>
> — [...]

And what follows are other conditions that do not apply in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get it to work like this:

```
struct B
{
    double operator()()
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
};

// my implementation does not have std::declval
template < typename T > T&& declval();

struct A
{
    B b;
    auto func() -> decltype(declval<B>().operator()())
    {
        return b();
    }
};
```

edit:
or since B is in scope already anyway no need for auto, -> decltype and declval

```
struct A
{
    B b;
    decltype(Q()()) func()
    {
        return b();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted to do. I did not know about declval. However, it was not direct answer for my question. So I picked other one. It helps me a lot:)