# How to deduce nested container value type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, containers

I have a container that stores another container. And I need to create an iterator for this container over nested container's values. This iterator should define an `operator*` but I do not know the nested container's value type to return. I can not guarantee that container has any `typedef` of the value. The only thing given is that each container has a proper `operator[]`. How to declare the `operator*`?

```
template<typename ContainerType>
struct MyIterator{
MyIterator(ContainerType& container, int32 indexA = 0, int32 indexB = 0)
    : Container(container)
    , IndexA(indexA)
    , IndexB(indexB)
{}

// NestedValueType needs to be replaced or declared somehow
NestedValueType& operator* ()
{
    return Container[IndexA][IndexB];
}

private:
    ContainerType& Container;
    int32 IndexA;
    int32 IndexB;
};
```

P.S. I have only C++11 features available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `decltype`:

```
auto operator*() -> decltype(Container[IndexA][IndexB])
{
    return Container[IndexA][IndexB];
}
```

For this to work you should move the data members from the bottom of the class to the top. [See this answer for the reason why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666387/2491746).

An alternative is to place `this->` before each data member access (`decltype(this->Container[this->IndexA][this->IndexB])`).

Comment: Probably I should mention that it was the first thing I've tried. The result is  `error C2065: 'Container' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: @teivaz Try putting `this->` in front of `Container` and `IndexA` and `IndexB`.

Comment: You could also move the data members to the top of the class instead of at the bottom and drop the `this->`.

Comment: With changes from comments it works. Just edit them to the answer and I'll resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++14 one solution would be to use `decltype(auto)` in the following way:

```
decltype(auto) operator* () {
  return (Container[IndexA][IndexB]);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69f50b6f4b14f1a)

Comment: I know about that solution, but I have only C++11 support.