# Why doesn't the compiler infer the type of member when using decltype?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, decltype

I just noticed this behavior in own code, so here is the naive question:

This:

```
struct A
{
    int get()
    {
        return a;
    }
    int a=1;
};   
int main() {}
```

Compiles of course fine, although when the declaration of member data lies **after** the function definition.

But then I don't understand why this:

```
struct A
{
    auto get() -> decltype(a)
    {
        return a;
    }
    int a=1;
};
```

does not compile(*). I have to write this:

```
struct A
{
    int a=1;
    auto get() -> decltype(a)
    {
        return a;
    }
};
```

Is there any language-related reasons why it's not ok, or is it just that the compilers have not implemented that ? I would expect to have the same behavior regardless of the order of the class members.

(*) tested with gcc 6.3 through Ideone.com

Comment: the compiler cannot deduce the type of something before it even knows it exists

Comment: Two different things. Declaration and definition. Class methods are not defined until the class declaration is complete. While declaring class methods and members (their types and their return types), the usual rules apply. Can't reference something that has not been declared yet.

Comment: But in first snippet, it does know about a, doesn't it ?

Comment: It "knows about a" because the body of the function is logically not defined until the entire class is declared. It's as if the compiler does not process the body of the class method until the closing brace is seen, first.

Comment: Note a similar thing does compile: `struct A { size_t get() { return sizeof(a); } int a; };`

Comment: This seems unrelated as `a` is not used in the declaration of  `get` here. @Bathsheba

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Yes, that seems to be the explanation.

Comment: It was indeed a dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16666387/193789 has the correct answer (Paragraph 3.4.1/7)

Comment: Thanks to all for your (correct) answers, I could accept all, but @Nelfeal has the lowest rep, so I'll accept his ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, `A::get` is declared, then `A::a` is declared, and only then (because `A` is fully declared), `A::get` is defined. At this point, in `A::get`, the compiler knows about `A::a`.

Consider this equivalent form:

```
struct A
{
    int get();
    int a=1;
};

inline int A::get()
{
    return a;
}
```

This would not be compilable for you second example:

```
struct A
{
    auto get() -> decltype(a); // What is "a"?
    int a=1;
};

inline auto A::get() -> decltype(A::a)
{
    return a;
}
```

The same "order of declaration" has to be respected when you declare types, for example:

```
struct A
{
    using IntType = int;
    auto get() -> IntType;
    int a=1;
};
```

You couldn't write like so:

```
struct A
{
    using IntType = decltype(a);
    auto get() -> IntType;
    int a=1;
};
```

Also note that this is not limited to return types: parameter types are also part of a function declaration. So this doesn't compile either:

```
struct A
{
    void f(decltype(a));
    int a=1;
};
```

Comment: @Bathsheba Why wouldn't it? The declaration `size_t get()` does not include anything about `a`.

Comment: You're correct. Have an upvote since I trolled your answer. I've also answered informally too.

Comment: i am not really the one to ask when it is about correct formal terms, but I wonder if "(because A is fully defined)" is really correct. Isnt the definition of its members part of `A`s definition? Did you mean to write "because A is fully declared" ?

Comment: @user463035818 True, although I don't think I've ever encountered a formal definition of "class definition". I have no idea if the standard defines that, or differentiates between class declaration and class definition. But I guess you could say the class definition includes the definition of its members.

Comment: well, sorry, on a second thought, my "correction" made it worse. `struct A;` is already a declaration (but no definition), not sure what is the correct wording for "fully declared"

Comment: @user463035818 Not sure. `struct A;` is a [forward declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) (without curly braces). So I guess we could call the next thing a full declaration, and then, when every member is defined, a definition.

Answer (score 5):

An informal answer if I may: `decltype` is a red herring.

All parts of a `return` type need to have already been seen by the compiler on the first pass.

For example,

```
template <size_t N> struct T{};

struct A
{
    T<sizeof(a)> get()
    {
        return T<sizeof(a)>();
    }
    int a;
};
```

will also fail, for the same reason: compilation passes if `int a;` is seen before `get()`.

Comment: For those who (like me) never heard that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Let me give some handwavy explanation why what you would like to write cannot work in general:

```
struct A {
    auto get() -> decltype(a)
    {
        return a;
    } 
    int a=1;
};
```

If this was allowed then either super complicated rules would be required or also the following would be allowed, while it actually does not make sense:

```
struct cyclic {
    auto a() -> decltype(b) {
        return ...;
    }
    auto b() -> decltype(a) { 
        return ...;
    }
};
```

I hope another answer will tell you the exact rules of the language that prevent to write something like that. I tried to give a motivation why it is actually better that we cannot write it.

Comment: Mmmh, I get the idea, but not sure it applies here: when defining a(), looking for b's type would indeed fail. On the opposite, in my example, the type of the data member is clearly known.

Comment: @kebs and thats were "super complicated rules" would be required. The current easy rule is "members are declared in the order they appear in the code". Compare this to "members are declared in any order, but if the declaration of one member depends on a second one they need to be declared in order [... ~500 special cases, notes and quirks due to interference with other rules ... ]" ;)